# Gatsby-Image + Storyblok : Serve Images in nextgen formats

Tags: javascript, html, css, gatsby, gatsby-image

I'm using `gatsby-storyblok-image` and Google PageSpeed Insights is telling me:

> serve images in nextgen formats!

... I thought gatsby-image was already doing this? Does this have to do with `gatsby-storyblok-image`, that it isn't doing it? Any ideas how I could fix it?